# What the compatible spark version for hive 2.3.9?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to set up Hadoop, Spark and Hive in my company, and use Spark as the execution engine for Hive. I'm facing compatibility issues with their versions.

These are my questions:

1. What is the working versions for Hive and Spark if you have any experience setting up
   such an ecosystem?
2. By any chance if you faced an error `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SPARK_RPC_SERVER_ADDRESS` how did you
   fix it?

Comment: Spark as Hive execution engine is deprecated in Hive v.3, along with MapReduce. Why would you set your company up with an outdated, soon to be abandoned, configuration?

Comment: @mazaneicha can you please provide me with a link to official documentation that specifies that the spark as hive execution engine is deprecated?  what is the recommended execution engine for Hive 3? tez?

Comment: The Hive wiki says that, I believe, but SparkSQL runs its own execution engine. Just because Spark uses the Hive metastore server, doesn't mean it needs to run MapReduce/Tez executions. Or you could use Presto or Impala instead of HiveServer2...